# XCode is resolving the wrong time.h file

Tags: c, xcode

I'm just getting my feet wet in C with some work in GStreamer, but seem to already be stuck.

I'm compiling the project in X Code using GNU99. The `<time.h>` header file that is part of the GStreamer code has no reference to `time_t`, which is used by some of the files.

Therefore I'm seeing:

```
/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers/glib/gbookmarkfile.h:171:11: 
Unknown type name 'time_t'; did you mean 'size_t'?
```

Do some C versions have varying header files for `<time.h>` that have done away with the `time_t` type? If so, is there a workaround?

Edit:

Looks like it has something to do with how XCode is searching for the `<time.h>` header file.

It should grab it from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/time.h`, but it's instead using one from `FFmpeg`

Under header search paths, I see this:

`/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers`

This setting is directly from the tutorial download

[image]

Comment: No, it has not been removed, doing so would break a lot of code.

Comment: I thought as much. Weird that it's not being found then.

Comment: I think the header file is incorrect then, and that its looking for `time_t` in the wrong `<time.h>`. I don't see it in that header when I look at the definition.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't be of too much help, I'm not familiar with Xcode. In theory `#Include <time.h>` should always work, but things can get messy, especially when multiple libraries exist on the system. My best suggestion would be to look at which specific `time.h` is being included, and if that version makes sense for your build environment.

Comment: I think you're correct in thinking this has to do with XCode. Compiling a fresh file on using GCC works fine with the `time_t` type. 

I'm guessing there is a problem with how it is searching for standard libraries : /

Comment: Indeed, its resolving to a different header file than `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/time.h`

Comment: If ffmpeg has a file named `time.h` in some include directory, and if you're telling the compiler to search that directory meaning it finds ffmpeg's file, that sounds like a bug in ffmpeg, not a problem with your compiler.  ffmpeg's file is masking the real one, and that's certainly a serious problem, but the compiler is properly doing exactly what you asked it to.

Comment: A quick google search revealed that to be the case. Thats a pain…

Answer (score 0):

My workaround solution was to add

```
#include </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/time.h>
```

to the FFMPEG `time.h` file.

Your path to the proper time header file may vary.